# Instantiate polymorphic member variable to be of appropriate type

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a Base class which contains a member variable std::unique_ptr< Base > next. I have several derived classes of Base.

I have a non-virtual function Base::grow() which initialises next. next will *always* point to an object of the type of the object calling grow.

That next is of the correct type is guaranteed via a virtual function call within Base::grow().

Creating a virtual function for each derived class is cumbersome and bug prone, hence my question: can I do this more succintly ?

My current minimal working example looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base{
  public:
    static const unsigned SIZE = 3;
    std::unique_ptr<Base> next;
    void grow(unsigned index){
      if (index < SIZE){
        print();
        next = get_new();
        next.get()->grow(index + 1);
      }
    }

    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> get_new(){
       return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Base());
      //return std::move(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Base())); (move not nec. see comments)
    }

    virtual void print (){
      std::cout << "a Base ";
    }
};

class Derived: public Base{
  public:
    virtual void print (){
      std::cout << "a Derived ";
    }
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> get_new(){
      return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived());
    }
};

int main(){
  std::unique_ptr<Base> b;
  b = std::unique_ptr<Base> (new Base());
  b->grow(0);

  std::unique_ptr<Base> c;
  c = std::unique_ptr<Base> (new Derived());
  c->grow(0);
}
```

Output is correct : a Base a Base a Base a Derived a Derived a Derived

In summary: I'd like a solution which does away tedious get_new, I would like Base::grow to determine what type to create based on type of calling object. I've considered using decltype, but without success.

Code snippet related to attempt to determine type at run-time:

```
typedef std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type DynamicBase;
next = std::unique_ptr<DynamicBase>(new DynamicBase());
```

DynamicBase above is always determined to be Base, even when `this` is pointer to Derived

Comment: C++ doesn't have a reliable way to obtain the type of the "calling object" at runtime (unless by "calling object" you mean `this` -- which you can obtain *limited* information about through RTTI), and even then you would need some reflection capability to create a new object of that type.  In short, there is no answer that satisfies your specific request, because it can't be done in C++.  There may be alternatives if you are open to them.

Comment: You don't need to `move` the expression `std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Base())`, which is already an rvalue.

Comment: @cdhowie I think that comment should be an answer.

Comment: @cdhowie yes by "calling object" I mean this. I append my attempt to determine type with RTTI in my question, perhaps you could elaborate on why it fails (determined type is always Base using my approach)

Comment: RTTI should give you the `Derived` type if that is the actual type of the object; if it gave you `Base` I would need to see example code to determine why.  However, even once you have the `std::type_info` object, there's not much you can do with it beyond get its name as a string and compare it to other `std::type_info` objects. C++ doesn't offer a way to construct a new object from `std::type_info` objects.

Comment: I do not use std::type_info (see code snippet at bottom of question). Admittedly I don't completely understand the code snippet, I'll need to do some research into what it's doing and why it fails. For now I'm going to accept Walter's answer. Thanks.

Comment: @newling `decltype()` is not RTTI -- the type of `decltype()` is evaluated statically, **at compile time**. RTTI involves the [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is impossible: you need at least one virtual function call, i.e. a virtual method overridden in every derived. Consider, for example, the situation that the derived class is defined in another compilation unit. How shall the code for the base class obtain a new derived object of unknown type if not using polymorphism?

Comment: It makes sense that get_new needs to be overridden in each class. But as the the virtual functions are all basically identical, it would be nice if there was some template-like approach to auto-generate them.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I came across the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (crtp) for the first time and I'm fairly sure that it can be used to such that `get_new` is only defined once.

The idea of crtp is well explained here: https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/